# Want MPMoviePlayerController to active throughout the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to stream audio clip from a url. Currently the `MPMoviePlayerController` working fine on the current `ViewController` where the `MPMoviePlayerController` initiate and the play action initiate.

Also the streaming working fine when the app goes background.

But, if I dismiss or go back from the Current `ViewController`, `MPMoviePlayerController` stop playing.
But my requirement is `MPMoviePlayerController` should continue playing/streaming throughout the app regardless of the navigation through view controllers.

In other words, each and every view controller should have `MPMoviePlayerController` controls visible for user to pause or stop the play manually.

How do I do it?

This is my current code.

```
// Initiate Audio Player in ViewDidLoad of SecondViewController

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
self.moviePlayer.view.hidden = NO;
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, videoContainer.frame.size.width, videoContainer.frame.size.height)];
[self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
self.moviePlayer.backgroundView.hidden = YES;

[videoContainer addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];


// Play method in SecondViewController

NSURL *audioUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:strMessageUrl];
self.moviePlayer.contentURL=audioUrl;
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

If user go back to `FirstViewController`, it stops

Comment: You can create the instance of movieplayer in appdelegate or in any shared class because they will be always in memory and add controls on AppDelegate.window

Comment: Did I understand you right: you have a stationary area where the video is played. And you want to transit between screens (i.e. view controllers), while video player remains unmoved ?

Comment: @David Yes. Its not video but audio streaming. Player should visible throughout the all the view controllers and remains playing

Comment: You can add your MovieController on Window, it will stay alive always.

Comment: @iphonic Yes, I did that. Play Controls remain visible. But player stops playing when going back to previous view controller

Comment: Thanks all, I was able to do it in Delegete level

Answer (score 0):

Put condition to check movie player is null or not.

```
if(!self.moviePlayer)
{
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
self.moviePlayer.view.hidden = NO;
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, videoContainer.frame.size.width, videoContainer.frame.size.height)];
[self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
self.moviePlayer.backgroundView.hidden = YES;

[videoContainer addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
}
```